# D3JS force layout center image

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm using force layout with d3js to draw a network graph
the problem is that my SVG is truncated (see the image bellow)
[image]
how to get the whole image ?
i'm using this to initialise the chart :

```
var width = 1200,
        height = 1000,
        root;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");
```

Comment: You are asking how to force the nodes to remain in the visible area?

Comment: Yes @AndrewReid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first simple step i suggest simply to scale the viewport...

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
        .attr("viewBox", `${-width/2} ${-height/2} ${width*2} ${height*2}`)
```

Or you can compute bbox of all nodes and set viewbox more percise

Comment: yes here https://imgur.com/eR0Julu the svg is smaller I don't know if we can do something..

Comment: yes here https://imgur.com/eR0Julu the svg is smaller I don't know if we can do something..

Comment: @DanyM can you share working code with https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-LcKwy-wgQdF6iVVITYp?